# JSON-Schema add property to the item conditionally

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following JSON data

```
[
  {
    "type": "social_media_profiles",
    "data": {
      "profiles": [
        {
          "key": "twitter",
          "data": "username",
          "field": "handle",
          "label": "Tweet"
        },
        {
          "key": "customLink",
          "data": "abc",
          "field": "url",
          "label": "Click",
          "color": {
            "button": "red",
            "text": "green",
            "border": "yellow"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

and following jsong schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["type", "data"],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "social_media_profiles"
        ]
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "allOf": [
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "const": "social_media_profiles"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "data": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": ["profiles"],
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "properties": {
                "profiles": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["data", "field", "key"],
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                      "data": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Data contains either profile url, handle id, etc."
                      },
                      "field": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": ["url", "handle", "id", "tel"],
                        "description": "Type of field value."
                      },
                      "key": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Social media name used to distinguish each social network"
                      },
                      "label": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Label to display on the landing page"
                      }
                    },
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "if": {
                          "properties": {
                            "key": {
                              "const": "customLink"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "then": {
                          "properties": {
                            "color": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "additionalProperties": false,
                              "required": [],
                              "properties": {
                                "button": {
                                  "type": "string"
                                },
                                "text": {
                                  "type": "string"
                                },
                                "border": {
                                  "type": "string"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to add new property `color` to the `profiles` item based on the condition when `key` of the item is `customLink`.

If `key` is not `customLink` then `color` property should not be there.

Validating the schema from `https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/` is giving error

```
 Found 2 error(s)

 Message: JSON does not match all schemas from 'allOf'. Invalid schema indexes: 0.
 Schema path: #/items/allOf

    Message: JSON does not match schema from 'then'.
    Schema path: #/items/allOf/0/then/then
```

**How can I append new property conditionally based on the sibling property value?**

Comment: You're MOST of the way there, but not quite. Let's see what we can do... =]

Answer (score 0):

In your `profiles.items` schema, you defined `additionalProperties: false`.

`additionalProperties` depends on the `properties` defined in the same schema object, meaning that `color` would always be dissallowed.

You can separate out your concerns into "what properties are allowed", and "if their values are valid".

Moving the validation for the `color` object into `profiles.properties` allows you to maintain `additionalProperties: false` in that object level.

The schema values of the `properties` object are only applied to the instance location for the keys, if they exist (hence needing to use `required` to require that specific keys are... required).

Having simplified the condional section, you end up with a cleaner Schema.

You now only need to define the condition under which `color` is required, without worrying about what the value should look like.

Sudo code: if `key` is `customLink`, then require `color`, else dissallow `color`.

```
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "key": {
        "const": "customLink"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "color"
    ]
  },
  "else": {
    "not": {
      "required": [
        "color"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Using `not`, you can invert the validation result of the applied subschema, which is what you need to do when you want to define that a specific property is NOT allowed.

Here's a live demo to play with: https://jsonschema.dev/s/C9V6N

And for prosperity, here's the full schema, with one or two redundancies removed.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "type",
      "data"
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "social_media_profiles"
        ]
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "allOf": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "profiles"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "profiles": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "required": [
                    "data",
                    "field",
                    "key"
                  ],
                  "additionalProperties": false,
                  "properties": {
                    "data": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "Data contains either profile url, handle id, etc."
                    },
                    "field": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "enum": [
                        "url",
                        "handle",
                        "id",
                        "tel"
                      ],
                      "description": "Type of field value."
                    },
                    "key": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "Social media name used to distinguish each social network"
                    },
                    "label": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "Label to display on the landing page"
                    },
                    "color": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "additionalProperties": false,
                      "properties": {
                        "button": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "text": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "border": {
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "if": {
                        "properties": {
                          "key": {
                            "const": "customLink"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "then": {
                        "required": [
                          "color"
                        ]
                      },
                      "else": {
                        "not": {
                          "required": [
                            "color"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as of now I'm doing the same thing. But this does not solve my issue. The `color` property is optional even in case of `customLink` but when present should be validated according to the properties defined under the `color` property.

If I set it to not required for other types, the value can still be accepted for non allowed types which I don't want.

Comment: `color` is always optional? Sorry I'm unclear what you're asking. It sounds like you're now providing additional requirements which you didn't include in your question. Can you add some more examples of what you want to be VALID and INVALID please?

Comment: "not > required" is not "not required". `not` inverts the assertion result, as explained. A schema of `{ "not": {} }` would make everything invalid. It's the equivalent of `false` as a boolean schema.